# Netbeans Jlabel visibility when switching tabs

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a jframe program where I have 2 tabs (Home & About) .. now I would like to display a jlabel in the about tab only when a button is clicked , I managed to do that by using jLabel5.setVisible(true); ... it works fine , but when I go back to the home tab and go back
again to the about tab , the jlabel is gone so I have to press again so it can appear ... is there a way that I can make it stay there without it resetting everytime i switch tabs? thanks ... this is a gif showing what exactly my problem is https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkuy1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could share the code, however there might be a work around, you could try to create a "flag" which is only a variable that is going to be true or false, create a variable flag that will change to true once you click in your button and then, when you pass to the About tab you will check if flag is true then jLabel5.setVisible(true) else jLabel5.setVisible(false), remember to initialize the flag variable as false.

Hope this work around works for you

Comment: here just to make it more clear , I made a gif showing exactly what the problem is , http://imgur.com/LEaYQxL notice how it works fine when I click the button , the pop up appears .. but when I go back to the home screen and back to the about screen its gone (i have to click it again) I want it to stay there if you know what I mean

Comment: This is the code https://gyazo.com/29eb31c7fddc1e3bfd72b07a5f199d79 (jlabel5 is the popup)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make this: when you click the button you set the setVisible(true) and also set "true" a false boolean. So you click, the boolean wasClicked, that was false became true, and before you write if wasClicked is true: setVisible(true). A code example:

```
boolean wasClicked = false;

if(wasClicked == true) {
jLabel5.setVisible(true);
}
```

When button is clicked (actionlistener):

```
wasClicked = true;
jLabel5.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how I should put the code? I keep getting an error with the line of ''wasClicked'' here just to make it more clear , I made a gif showing exactly what the problem is , http://imgur.com/LEaYQxL notice how it works fine when I click the button , the pop up appears .. but when I go back to the home screen and back to the about screen its gone (i have to click it again) I want it to stay there if you know what I mean

Comment: You don't have to insert the boolean and the if in the actionlistener, but only the wasClicked = true and the setVisible.

Comment: I tried it , I got no error and program runs fine ... but when I switch tabs , the pop up disappears , I have to click the button again .. here's the code https://gyazo.com/cd03165a334f8eb0a96633e75c0d80a9

Comment: You have to insert the boolean instantiation and the if in the main class and the true setting of wasClicked and the visible in the action listener.